# The taskModuleRequest.Data is passing the ID value but cannot pass the taskModuleRequest.Data value to the objleaverequest

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, botframework

**Here is code I want to pass taskModuleRequest data value to my object and that value pass to the parameter of CreateLeaveRequest method.**

```
protected override async Task<TaskModuleResponse> OnTeamsTaskModuleSubmitAsync 
                                        (ITurnContext<IInvokeActivity> turnContext, 
                                         TaskModuleRequest taskModuleRequest, 
                                         CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{    
    turnContext = turnContext ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(turnContext));
    var activity = (Activity)turnContext.Activity;
    this.RecordEvent(nameof(this.OnTeamsTaskModuleFetchAsync), turnContext);

    taskModuleRequestdata objleaverequest = new taskModuleRequestdata();
    objleaverequest.LeaveID =Convert.ToInt32(taskModuleRequest.Data);

    try
    {
   
        var adaptivecard = MessageFactory.Attachment(
                LeaveRequestCard.CreateLeaveRequest(objleaverequest.LeaveID,
                    Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\Cards\LeaveRequestCard.json"));
        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(adaptivecard, cancellationToken);
        return null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        this.logger.LogError(ex, "Error in fetching task module.");
        return null;
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: do you really think that we can spot where's wrong instantly with just the message in the title and the posted code? At least we need to know where the error is thrown at, in this case you have a try-catch, for debugging you can even remove it completely (some kind of irrelevant code in this case), or at least post the stacktrace so that we can see where it goes wrong.

Comment: @KingKing in code there is nothing error, but objleaverequest.LeaveID is set is 0. but I want to set the value taskModuleRequest.data in objleaverequest.LeaveID

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32` would throw exception if the input is not in a correct format, so if you get `0`, that means the `taskModuleRequest.Data` is `"0"` or `null`. So we cannot do much with such passed-in data. Something is wrong before the code you posted.

Comment: @KingKing, sir taskModuleRequest.Data is fetched data properly. when I have converted objleaverequest.LeaveID =Convert.ToInt32(taskModuleRequest.Data) the objleaverequest.LeaveID in the blank. the reason is taskModuleRequest.Data is object type how to I solved the problems to send the data by interger type without 0

Comment: do you see any value contained in `taskModuleRequest.Data`? it may be boxed by `object` but its actual type should be `IConvertible` and usually a `string` in this case. Otherwise what you have is an exception, not a returned value of `0`.